# Selecting a file in MacOS Finder when running Selenium / Capybara test script

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm attempting to upload a file on a page that I'm testing.  The attach_file method within Capybara will not work here.  The reason being that the upload feature is using a JS library named file-uploader [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).

I'm actually able to invoke a mouse click in order to open a Finder window (in Mac OS) to allow me to select a file to open, however I'm not sure of how to work within this window.  Essentially I'd like to select a file from my desktop and just click 'Open'.

Is there a way for me to work within this window to simply choose a file by its name and then click 'Open'?

I'm working in Firefox.

Dragging the file from my desktop into a div would also work, but I can not find a way to do that in Capybara either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a browser automation tool & as such any interaction with other components of operating systems is not possible. Once a browser opens a file open/Finder window, it's no longer the browser that you're interacting with. There are tools out there which can handle them, but i am not familiar enough to give a detailed response. Google the Robot framework, or AutoIt for starters.

Alternatively, since it's a JS library you're dealing with which handles the upload, you MAY be able to use the JavascriptExecutor to call library functions directly, which doesn't simulate the user experience, but may be enough to get past your hurdle.

Comment: I'd love to use AutoIt but I'm strictly testing on a Mac.  I've had much experience with AutoIt in the past.

Is there a way I can integrate applescript into what I'm trying to do?